# Combing Search Terms in gtrendsR package?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, google-search, google-trends

Within R, I am using the package gtrendsR. On the web version of google trends, one can "combine" search terms by putting plus signs between them as follows:
[image]

I believe this effectively makes the search term apple+orange a kind of sum of both of these search terms. I know one could write multiple separate search terms within gtrendsR, such as `gtrends(c("apple", "orange")`, but this is not what I want to do.

Is there any way to perform the same operation shown in the picture (apple+orange) with the gtrendsR package? I have been unable to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?

```
> library(gtrendsR)
> res <- gtrends("apple+orange")
> plot(res)
```

yields pretty much your answer (modulo different time resolution which you can adjust).

[image]

Comment: thank you! I had read a blog post on a different website saying this wasn't easily possible, but you are correct!

Comment: Feel free to 'accept' (click on 'tick') the answer and 'upvote' (click on 'up' triangle) if it suits.  That is how StackOverflow works and filters helpful answers.